# Where to put Java libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, mule-studio

I'd like to know how I can add Java libraries to an Eclipse project on a development machine so that they can be added to an Eclipse project without causing errors when someone who has the library in a different location.  For example, one developer might add an external JAR in `C:\Java`, but another might have the same JAR somewhere else.  (Where's `C:\Java` on Mac OS?)  I thought I might set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, but I can't figure how to add an external JAR from the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.  I'd like to do this so that it works with any workspace.  Is this possible?

This is specifically for use with Anypoint Studio, but I think the same problem would exist with any Eclipse-based IDE.

Comment: You need to add it to the build path of the project to just make it work locally. If you want to work your project over different OS you might want to build it with a build tool which will point to the repo like Maven or or Ant.

Comment: This is why dependency managers exist, for java you want maven.

Comment: Gradle is considered by many to be the evolution of Maven, combining the best of both Ant and Maven. I recommend considering it before Maven. But if that big of a change is too much, look at the alternatives in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's recommended to either embed JARs directly into the project, usually in a `/lib` folder of the project, [as described here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html#classpath); or to use a tool like Gradle or Maven to manage dependencies, both of which have nice plugins to support their use in Eclipse.

Another alternative would be to use a [Classpath Variable](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fbuildpath%2Fref-preferences-classpath-variables.htm) to refer to the JAR(s), which abstracts the physical location so that it can be set on a per-workspace basis.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to add library to eclipse project is creating a directory - **lib** in your project directory. Then add the whole lib to you eclipse class path. You can follow these step to add a lib to class path -

1. Right click on project and select **properties**
2. Select **Java Build Path**
3. click **Add Library** and create **User Library**
4. Now add **External Jars** to this library create at step 3.
   By this a .classpath file is crated in you project directory and the `CLASSPATH` problem will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to do that would be using Maven, or a similar build system that can construct your Classpath base on dependencies.

You can add the dependencies to your pom and having the jars in your local maven repository in the machine.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Because in any other approach you will need to maintain everything manually, and when having different OS the path will change.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is just the IDE that will help to write code and assemble the project (JAR, WAR, ... ). You can add your external jars from wherever you want, and when you want to export your project (with eclipse) you may choose to package the required libraries into the jar.

However, I recommend always to use maven (or something like ) to avoid this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

- **Part1**:(**import** .jar file as library in Eclipse)

You make a new project to Eclipse(name:Project1)
 When you *open* it you see **JRE System Library[java version something]**

**1**.**right click** on *JRE System Library*

**2**.Go->*Build Path*->*Configure Build Path*

**3**.You can see (***Up right Corner*** the button[***add jars*** or **add** **external *jars***]

*Here i advise you to choose the **first(add jars)** but..

*First **copy**(or move) the **(name).jar** inside the     project((example):Project 1)

*Now you can add it with the button(**add jars**).

***In this way when you finish your project the (name).jar will be
 imported inside the project(If you export it as a .jar from Eclipse)**

..Now you can call any method of **(name).jar** just(import it into the class
you want to use and call it)